# Add/Delete an AddressEntry to Addressentries

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to add/delete an AddressEntry to/from AddressEntries.
I could delete the first Item from AddressEntries with the following code:

```
Private Sub DoSmth() 
..
Dim AE As Outlook.AddressEntries
..
AE.Item(1).Delete
..
End Sub
```

I have read the documentation of Microsoft but I found no example. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentries.add).

Could any one explain me how to add an AddressEntry to the AddressEntries?

Comment: Do you use excel vba to create mail or just outlook vba?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentries.add

Comment: Outlook help tells `AddressList.AddressEntries Property 
Returns the AddressEntries collection for the specified object. Read-only.` that this property is read-only.

Comment: Yes right! but the question is how to use the function Add in address entries

Answer (score 0):

I've tried following approach and `.Delete` worked out. It appears that considering `AddressList.AddressEntries Property Returns the AddressEntries collection for the specified object` you have to go through items of a **specific** collection to remove it.

```
Sub test()


Dim ae As AddressEntry

For Each ae In Application.Session.AddressLists("your_address_list_name").AddressEntries
    Debug.Print ae.Type & "->" & ae.Name & "->" & ae.Address
    ' this worked:
    ' ae.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

So, if you run that code, you will see that when you add an entry, the `Type` property is the name of the address list, which in turn is a collection name.

**Update**
The code below also works properly, so you can delete it by `Item` index:

```
Debug.Print Application.Session.AddressLists("your_address_list_name").AddressEntries.Item(5)

' the line below deletes an entry
Application.Session.AddressLists("your_address_list_name").AddressEntries.Item(5).Delete

Debug.Print Application.Session.AddressLists("your_address_list_name").AddressEntries.Item(5)
```

**Update 2**
Here is the decision that worked for adding entry. It is taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentries) (to get to certain addresslist entries collection) and from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentries.add) (to get required parameters for `.Add` method) but it maybe not that elegant, because, to tell the truth, I'm not that strong in Outlook vba.
Code:

```
Sub AddEntry()
Dim myNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim myAddressList As AddressList
Dim myAddressEntries As AddressEntries

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myAddressList = myNameSpace.AddressLists("your_address_list_name")
Set myAddressEntries = myAddressList.AddressEntries

' Option 1
myAddressEntries.Add Type:="Type", Name:="Name", Address:="Address"

' Option 2 - can be used as independent of declarations line
Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("your_address_list_name").AddressEntries.Add "Type1", "Name1", "Address1"

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I could already delete address entries with my code by selecting a specified Item and delete it. But i couldn't add an address entry to address entries using the function Addressentries.Add.
Do you have any idea?